# Reference request - book on Euclidean space and particle and rigid body kinematics

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, kinematics

Ideally, I'd like a comprehensive book that encompasses both subjects: it builds the notion of "space" as related to our physical world (no relativity, though) from the ground up, giving it mathematical rigor (admittedly I am not sure if Euclidean space is in fact what I am looking for), and then develops the theory of particle and rigid body motion, with formal treatments of the different types of motions, such as translational and rotational. There's no need for the book to tackle the kinetics of these motions. Obviously, if it's in there, I won't complain.

Do you know of anything that might fit this description? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a specific title but these topics are usually covered in Dynamics. Dynamics is the second course of a Statics and Dynamics sequence that is usually taken by mechanical engineering students.

Comment: @JohnDouma I'm looking for something more mathematically oriented and rigorous than a dynamics/mechanics course taken up in mechanical engineering. I have a degree in mechanical engineering, and I'm looking to take a more in-depth look into what I saw during my undergrad years.